# How to count the unique rows with a groupby statement in R

Tags: r, group-by

I am trying to count the amount of unique rows with a groupby of 3 columns.
I have tried working with dplyr but without success. I'm quite new to this so I was wondering if someone can help me.

```
library(dplyr)

ds <- read.csv("env12k10.csv")

ds % > %
  group_by(ds$age,ds$occupation,ds$workclass) % > %
    sum(!duplicated(ds))
```

The pipeline doesn't work and gives an error code "could not find function "% > %"

and the sum(!duplicated(ds)) is something I found on a different post for summing up the unique rows.

Comment: the pipe is ``%>%`` not ``% > %``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of R's language semantics are *pre-fix*, meaning that the first "thing" in an expression is the function or operator. In the generic sense, pre-fix means `<function> <arg1> <arg2> ...`; R encapsulates the arguments within parens (lisp-like) and comma-separates them (C-like), so `<function>(<arg1>, <arg2>, ...)`.

R has some exceptions: some binary operators are allowed as "in-fix", meaning `<arg1> <inline-operator> <arg2>`. There are a few notable in-fix operators that are direct and "un-decorated", such as math operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), logical negation (`!`), assignment (`=` and `<-`, nearly synonymous), and comparisons (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`). *All* infix operators can be called in a pre-fix notation, as in

```r
1 + 1
# [1] 2
`+`(1, 1)
# [1] 2
```

The converse is not true: not all pre-fix operators ("functions") can be used in in-fix notation. Notably, while `c(1, 2)` works, `1 c 2` does not.

So there needs to be a way to direct R to interpret a function as what I'll call a "default" function (pre-fix only), or to interpret as one whose default operation will be in an in-fix mode (with pre-fix as an option). The simplest method is to "decorate" the function name with something.

Early developers chose the `%` sign. I don't know why, but I believe there needs to be something to make it unambiguous. So `%` it is.

Complicating things *slightly* (but in a consistent manner), one cannot do

```r
%func% <- function(a, b) { ... }
```

because, by the nature of the parser in-fix exception, it notices the `%func%` and thinks that it is a *call* to an in-fix operator (albeit missing its first argument), and it will error with `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%func%"`. (Side note: normally, variable names should not include `%`.) The canonical way in R to reference a variable name that does not subscribe to the "normal R variable naming convention" is to surround it in backticks. Technically, all variable *can* be surrounded in backticks, but some *must* be surrounding in them to reference them in a non-infix way. For example, `` `c`(1,2) `` also works.

So the way to define an in-fix operator is the same way to use it as a pre-fix operator is the same way to look at it, as in

```r
`%q%` <- function(a, b) a*b+1
1 %q% 3
# [1] 4
```

From there, realize that the in-fix function we've defined is `%q%`, **not** `% q %`. The two are distinct symbols.

So from that, your example is a bit clearer. In

```r
ds % > %
  group_by(ds$age,ds$occupation,ds$workclass) % > %
    sum(!duplicated(ds))
```

R notices the two `%` symbols and infers that the in-fix operator is `% > %`, which does not exist. (Admittedly, part of me expects R to notice the `%` surrounded by spaces, so I would not have been surprised if it tried the modulus operation between `ds` and `>`, intuitively illogical.)

Since this uses `dplyr::group_by`, it's easy to infer that you mean the `%>%` function and in-fix operator. Try this instead:

```r
ds %>%
  group_by(ds$age,ds$occupation,ds$workclass) %>%
  sum(!duplicated(ds))
```

But since I'm correcting code, let me make a couple of other changes:

- *Rarely* should one use `$` notation within a `dplyr` pipe: at best, it is inefficient; if there is *any* portion of the pipe before the `$` use that re-orders, adds-to, re-assigns, or otherwise alters the data originating in `ds`, then the results will be different. The really bad news is that often this means the results you will get are incorrect, but there will be no warning or error. Data corruption. There are times when using `$` notation on the original object is appropriate, but they are truly the exception, often within an aggregation operation, etc.
- Similarly, `duplicated(ds)` will be calling `duplicated` on the *original* frame, not the grouped data resulting from `group_by`; if you want to refer to the frame *as it is at this point in the pipe*, use `.`, as n `!duplicated(.)`.
- The `dplyr`-canonical ways to count distinct rows include

  ```r
  ds %>%
    count(age, occupation, workclass)
  ds %>%
    group_by(age, occupation, workclass) %>%
    count()
  ds %>%
    group_by(age, occupation, workclass) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
  ```

Comment: Thank you alot you made it really clear!